# Apache mod_rewrite: return a specific file if no file/directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, config

I'm writing a CMS that uses JavaScript to load the content of a page from the database. But I don't want hashes `#` in my URLs.

When a path is requested `/cms/post/123`, Apache should load the file `/cms/index.html`. But if there's already a file under the path, for example `/cms/image.png`, Apache should return the file. Another point is that when for example `/cms/admin` or `/cms/admin/post/123` is requested the file `/cms/admin.html` should be returned. The directory of the CMS may be different.

Comment: Thanks for detailed requirements, what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using these rules in an htaccess file in your `/cms/` directory

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# if file exists, serve the file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if request is for admin, load admin.html
RewriteRule ^admin/ admin.html [L]

# everything else gets routed to index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

You can place this in any directory that the CMS is in.

Comment: Looks great, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks for the fast answer!